# RAID 10 failed booting when one drive removed

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, raid, mdadm

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 Server with Software RAID 10 (4×500GB SSD). 
I tried to test a disk failure by shutting down the server and removing (physically) one of the HDDs.

The problem is when the server is trying to boot to Linux, it goes to `initramfs` and does not succeed. I thought it will run normally because of the mirroring RAID 10.

If I test the disk failure when the Linux is running (I remove the device by typing command `mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1`) it works normally, I can test disk failure and also recovering. The problem is when the system is rebooting and there is a disk failure.

Is this a bug in Ubuntu 16.04 for RAID 10? Or am I still missing something?